# Error : CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'X'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ienumerable

I'm trying to get data from a LocalDb into my MVC Controller. I'm using this code but doesn't work :

```
 public StatusCategory BranchIdSearch(string branch){
     var categoryId = _context.StatusCategories
         .Where(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch))
         .Select(a => a.StatusCategoryId)
         .ToList();
     return categoryId;
 }
```

Error :

> CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'ProjectName.Data.Models.StatusCategory

StatusCategory.cs File :

```
public class StatusCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int StatusCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string StatusCategoryTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Status> Status { get; set; }
}
```

**LocalDb Table :**

[StatusCategory Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbuk8.png)

Need help, Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are retrieving a `List<int>` instead of a single `StatusCategory`. To retrieve a single object or value you must use `FirstOrDefault`. Change your query to this to retrieve a single complete object:

```
var categoryId = _context.StatusCategories.Where(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch))
     .FirstOrDefault();

 return categoryId;
```

In case you really want only the Id then you must change the return type and the query:

```
public int BranchIdSearch(string branch){
 var categoryId = _context.StatusCategories.Where(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch))
     .Select(a => a.StatusCategoryId)
     .FirstOrDefault();
 return categoryId;
}
```

Comment: Probably better to return `int?` and do `FirstOrDefault()?.StatusCategoryId` to return `null` for no match instead of 0 which  might be a valid id.

Comment: @juharr Databases don't assign '0' as a valid autogenerated Id, I am used to use '0' as an invalid Id. Also, your recomendation will retrieve a lot of unneeded data, in case the table contains a lot of data per record this will be a performance killer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return many, i.e. a list, but your function says that it should return one.

If you want to return one `StatusCategory`.

```
public StatusCategory BranchIdSearch(string branch){
    return _context.StatusCategories.FirstOrDefault(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch));
}
```

If you want to return one `StatusCategoryId`

```
public int? BranchIdSearch(string branch){
    return _context.StatusCategories.Where(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch)).Select(a => (int?)x.StatusCategoryId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you want to return many `StatusCategory`.

```
public IList<StatusCategory> BranchIdSearch(string branch){
    return _context.StatusCategories.Where(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch)).ToList();
}
```

If you want to return many `StatusCategoryId`

```
public IList<int> BranchIdSearch(string branch){
    return _context.StatusCategories.Where(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch)).Select(a => x.StatusCategoryId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: That second one should return `int` as it's the type of `StatusCategoryId` and similarly the 4th should be a `IList<int>`.  Though the second maybe should be `int?` and it should be `FirstOrDefault()?.StatusCategoryId` so that no match returns `null` instead of 0 which might be a valid id.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, I've updated my answer. I kept thinking `StatusCategoryId` was an enum for some weird reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting a `List<int>` instead of a single `StatusCategory`

You can use directly  `FirstOrDefault` or `Single`

`FirstOrDefault` will return the found object or null

`Single` will return the object or throw an exception if there is more then one object with the condition

```
 public StatusCategory BranchIdSearch(string branch){
     var categoryId = _context.StatusCategories.Where(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch))
         .FirstOrDefault(a => a.StatusCategoryId);

     return categoryId;
 }

 public StatusCategory BranchIdSearch(string branch){
     var categoryId = _context.StatusCategories.Where(a => a.StatusCategoryTitle.Contains(branch))
         .Single(a => a.StatusCategoryId);

     return categoryId;
 }
```

Comment: `Single` also throws if there are no matches.  There's also `SingleOrDefault` that will return null for no matches and throw for more than one or `First` which will return the first match or throw if there are no matches.